# Sharing data between steps serialization error

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm passing data between steps (large objects) but i'm getting a serialization error what is the maximum quantity of data that i have to pass and how can i get a solution for this problem ?

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to serialize object of type: class org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext

Comment: I have implemented Serializable to the model and now it's working but sometimes i get null pointer exception error maybe because i'm executing split job flow (parallel steps) is it Thread safe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `implements Serializable` to your object class.
Anything saved to the jobRepository needs to be serializable. This may be used as part of the step execution context data that is saved.